# New Cygwin user with command difficulties

Tags: cygwin

I am new to Cygwin and programming so these are basic problems. I was using PowerShell to learn some basic command line usage but then I learned Unix is better for what I intend to do so I downloaded Cygwin because I have Windows 7. My problem is that I do not know how to write multiple commands. In PowerShell you pressed shift+enter to get to a new line but this doesn't work on Cygwin. My book says write:

```
$ pwd
$ cd ~
```

but I cant get a new line by hitting enter. If I type a "\" it lets me go to the next line but then makes me space to write new command. This cant be right? I'm sure it's a super simple solution but I can't find the answer on the net.

Comment: I get a newline every time I press enter on my cygwin terminal running on Windows 7. Something could have gone wrong with your installation if you can't press enter to get a new line.

Comment: hi alvits. i do get a new line but it runs the command. im trying to run multiple commands like :pwd and cd ~, and then hit enter to run both commands. my book tells me to type in multiple lines then run it. i hope this makes sense.

Comment: Semi-colon `;` in bash is a newline. To type multiple commands before you hit enter, all you need is to put semicolon `;` between the commands. For example, `pwd; cd ~`.

Comment: @alvits: `;` isn't a newline; it's a command separator.

Comment: difference? im super new.

Comment: @KeithThompson - I thought in Windows there's no such thing as command separator. I tried my best not to confuse the OP and avoided the phrase command separator.

Comment: @patrick - Are you trying to run multiple commands interactively? Or are you trying to run a script? In powershell I believe it is called batch file. In cygwin it is called script. If this is what you want to accomplish, then all you need is a text editor to write the commands in a script.

Comment: @alvits: Cygwin is a Unix-like emulation layer that runs on top of Windows. It uses the same `bash` shell that's commonly used on Unix and Linux systems. The use of `;` as a command separator (I'm not sure the documentation uses that exact term) is a feature of the `bash` shell, and of pretty much every other Unix shell.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that you already have a shell prompt. The shell prompt can vary depending on your settings, but by default it should be something like `$`.

If you have a shell prompt, simply typing

```
pwd
```

followed by the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key should execute the `pwd` command, printing the name of your current directory.

To run two commands on a single line, you can type, for example:

```
pwd ; cd ~
```

again followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The semicolon is a command separator, letting you enter multiple commands on a single line.

Note that in this case that's not particularly useful; you might as well type the `pwd` and `cd ~` commands on separate lines.

Of course the `$` is your shell prompt; don't type the `$`, just the command.

The default shell in Cygwin is `bash`, which has a *lot* of features. You can read the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html), but you probably just want to learn to execute simple commands first. (And most of the power of any Unix-like system is the commands you execute *from* the shell, more than the shell itself.)

Comment: ok i think i understand, it just tripped me up because i was using powershell and cygwin had a different format. so when you say "you might as well type the pwd and cd ~ commands on separate lines." you mean just type pwd then hit enter. and then type in cd ~ and hit enter. so it looks like this: 

Computer User@sowhat ~
$ pwd
/home/Computer User

Computer User@sowhat ~
$ cd ~              --cant get it to format right like you did in my original comment

Comment: @patrick - Windows has DOS prompt usually displaying the drive letter like `C:\>` In cygwin and UNIX shells, such a prompt display a little differently. In cygwin, bash shell prompt is usually in the format `username@hostname dirname $`.